# yet another confusion with multiprocessing error, 'module' object has no attribute 'f'

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I know this has been answered before, but it seems that executing the script directly "python filename.py" does not work. I have Python 2.6.2 on SuSE Linux.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(1)
def f(x):
    return x*x
p.map(f, [1, 2, 3])
```

Command line:

```
> python example.py
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 231, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 57, in worker
    task = get()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 339, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using python multiprocessing Pool in the terminal and in code moudles for Django or Flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947876/using-python-multiprocessing-pool-in-the-terminal-and-in-code-moudles-for-django)

Comment: @jb. that post is much later than this one, this was 2010, that one is 2013

Comment: Age is irrevelant there is consensus on meta that question with better answer should be chosen, and another one has IMO better answer.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Restructure your code so that the `f()` function is defined before you create instance of Pool. Otherwise the worker cannot see your function.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

p = Pool(1)
p.map(f, [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: NOTE: A few years later, I've started writing an imap alternative [ https://github.com/gatoatigrado/vimap ], which makes this mistake more difficult (and makes it clear when threads are forked).

Comment: @Bartosz, Do you have any idea why this is not a problem in ipython notebooks?

Comment: @Framester: Odds are, ipython notebooks are using a "spawn" like approach to multiprocessing, rather than a "fork" based approach. The spawn based approach is to either launch a fresh process and import the main module (but not as `__main__`, to prevent it doing the `if __name__ == '__main__`:` stuff), or pickle interpreter state to transmit to child. `fork` semantics are faster, but only work on a single machine, and not on Windows. Spawn semantics can be made to work anywhere (e.g. Windows w/o `fork`), and can work on a cluster, and ipython notebooks are intended for multimachine cases.

Answer (score 7):

This one works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(1)
    p.map(f, [1, 2, 3])
```

I'm not 100% sure why your code does not work, but I guess the reason is that child processes launched by the `multiprocessing` module try to import the main module (to have access to the methods you defined), and the `if __name__ == "__main__"` stanza is required not to execute the initialization code where you set up your pool.

Comment: If one has to run such code through an interpreter on Windows is there any work around? This is the situation I'm confronted with doing some Python-Fu programming from the Gimp Python Console plugin.

Comment: @Tamás, it does not work for me either, `from multiprocessing import Pool`, `ImportError: cannot import name Pool`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your python file has the same name as a module:

- test.py
- test/

  - __init__.py

in pickle.py, you have the error coming from:

```
    def find_class(self, module, name):
      # Subclasses may override this
      __import__(module)
      mod = sys.modules[module] # <- here mod will reference your test/__init__.py
      klass = getattr(mod, name)
      return klass
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was solved by using `if __name__ == "__main__"` as pointed out by Tamás; in Eclipse for Windows the examples do not work under the interpreter. 
This is explained in
http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the fact that with `p = Pool(1)` the main process forks processes (threads vs processes) before it creates the function f. As stated in Bartosz answer the spawned processes do not have access to the new function.

```
def f1(x):
    ...

p = Pool(1) # p is spawned and is now an independent process, knows f1

def f(x): # p doesn't not share this object
    ...
```