# Python multiprocessing - probably failure when method name pass to Process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have problem with multiprocessing. Under you have the code (he's in couple of class and files, but i simplified it).
I suppose, that problem lies in pass method name which I want to multiply in multiprocessing.
Informations:
"args" is a list like as [(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)] so single "arg" like as (0,1)
This two files are in totally other calatogs
!!First file!!

```
from ... import EF
from ... import someclass

class performs():
    def action():
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):
            data.append(EF(self.method,list(arg),i))
        someclass.create_processes(*data)

    def method(self,fa,la):
        ...
```

!!second file!!

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Event
class EF(object):
    def __init__(self,name,args=list(),proc=1):
        self.name=name
        self.args=args
        self.proc=proc

class someclass:
    @staticmethod
    def create_processes(*functions):
        processes=dict()
        for function in functions:
            process=Process(target=function.name,args=function.args)
            process.start()
            processes[process.pid]=process
        for process in processes.values():
            process.join()
```

When I'm debugging, error comes, when program performing this instruction "process.start()"

Console:

```
File "C:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 371, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
AttributeError: 'performs' object has no attribute 'function'
```

or in other situation

```
File "C:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 116, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "...\performs.py", line 88, in method
...
```

I don't know it's important, but I have 64bit system, and installed Python and accesories for 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

The comment box is too small for this, but it seems like your code is working fine. I tested it by copying it in two files (like your environment), but it of course also works in a single file. That file you can find below: it is working as expected (save for the print statements output being mixed up, but that is to be expected).

So, most likely, your issue lies elsewhere? The error seems to indicate perhaps some inclusion order, like stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782961/yet-another-confusion-with-multiprocessing-error-module-object-has-no-attribu)?

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Event

class EF:
    def __init__(self, name, args=list(), proc=1):
        self.name = name
        self.args = args
        self.proc = proc

class someclass:
    @staticmethod
    def create_processes(*functions):
        processes=dict()
        for function in functions:
            process=Process(target=function.name,args=function.args)
            process.start()
            processes[process.pid]=process
        for process in processes.values():
            process.join()

class performs:
    def action(self, args):
        data = []
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):
            data.append(EF(self.mult, list(arg), i))
        someclass.create_processes(*data)

    def mult(self,fa,la):
        print '%d x %d = %d' % (fa, la, fa * la)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = performs()
    p.action([(x, x+1) for x in xrange(10)])
```