# Python: Multi-processing a function call inside for loop so that each call runs independently

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that encrypts a number and stores it in an list

```
encrypted = [[0]*10]*1000

def encrypt(i):
        encrypted[i]=bin(i)[2:].zfill(10).decode('hex')
```

The expression is much more complex than this. I am just stating an example.

Now I want to call the encrypt function inside a for loop  with multiple calls in different processes or threads - however due to GIL for CPU bound process, threads wont help - correct me if i am wrong.

```
for i in xrange(1000):
     encrypt(i)
```

So The loop should not wait for the encryption of one value to get over, for the next to start.

So when i=1 and encryption of 1 is taking place, For loop should increment and start encrypting 2, and then 3 simultaneously.

The results of encryption should be stored in encrypted list (order of results is not important).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143837/how-to-multi-thread-an-operation-within-a-loop-in-python

Comment: I think this example should help you batch up your values and have an optimal number of threads working in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`multithreading.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def encrypt(i):
    return bin(i)[2:].zfill(10).decode('hex')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)  # adjust to number of cores
    result = pool.map(encrypt, range(1000))
    print result
```

Comment: is there any other way to call encrypt concurrently without the use of map - as result of encrypt goes to an if statement .. if (len(encrypt(i))<16)): end all processes  ....just stating an example; iterating for true or false in results array would make unnecessary overhead.

Comment: got it.. i used imap_unordered instead of map Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Alright, first some advice. Depending on the number of threads you need to run you should check out [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) this sounds like the kind of project that could benefit heavily from pypy's features.

Here Is an edited example from the [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) docs if I understand what you need than this should point you in the right direction.

This code assumes that you have a list of encrypted numbers and that
your encrypt function handles adding the results to a list or storing them somehow.

```
def worker():
    while True:
        number = q.get()
        encrypt(number)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for number in numbers:
    q.put(number)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: Thanks @fern - though I read somewhere that for CPU bound processes, due to Global interpreter lock , running multiple threads will be of no use. Is there any other way to achieve the same task using multi-processing

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on the selected answer but if Pool's processes is set to None it will use the value returned by the cpu_count().