# Parallelizing loop in python

Tags: python

I have an agents population of 10,000 and each agent has its location [x,y], where x and y are random numbers between 0 and 100. I want to calculate distance between each agent and decide if they are neighbours and then store these information in 10000x10000 array. So far I've come up with the following:

```
for j in range(len(agents_population[1])):
    B[j,j:10000] = [
        True if distance.euclidean(agents_population[1][j],
            agents_population[1][i]) < r 
        else False for i in range(j,len(agents_population[1]))
      ]
```

Where *agents_population[1]* is a list of agents' coordinates (so in this case 10000-items list of 2-items lists: [[x1,y1], [x2,y2]...), *r* is radius and *B* is that array. In each iteration I calculate distance between agent *j* and agents *j+1* to 9999. However, each iteration of the loop is independent from each other, so I was thinking I could use all four cores of my processor instead of just one. I tried using `multiprocessing` module and Pool().map() function, but I wasn't able to make it work. I would be really grateful for any advice.

EDIT:

I tried using `multiprocessin` as follows:

```
def worker(j):
    B[j,j:10000] = [
        True if distance.euclidean(agents_population[1][j],
            agents_population[1][i]) < r 
        else False for i in range(j,len(agents_population[1]))
      ]

def mp_handler():
    p = Pool(4)
    p.map(worker, range(0))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp_handler() 

B[0,].tofile('foo.csv',sep=',')
```

I run it via cmd.exe, but when I open file foo.csv the results are different compared to when I run function worker with j=0. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not really an answer but if you're using python2, using xrange instead of range would save you creating 10,000 unused lists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143837/how-to-multi-thread-an-operation-within-a-loop-in-python

Comment: take a look at multiprocessing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dead simple example of using Multiprocessing Queue, Pool and Locking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887555/dead-simple-example-of-using-multiprocessing-queue-pool-and-locking)

Comment: Using multiple threads or processes to process data provides no guarantees on the order of the results. You will need to sort it after the `Pool.map` if order matters to you.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre @JaroslawMatlak I tried both `concurrent.futures` and `ThreadPool()`, they work, but it doesn't seem they parallelize anything, i.e. they compute similarly to the regular for-loop or even a bit slower :(