# Parallelize independent iterations of for loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, multiprocessing

I have 10 pandas data frames that I am looping to apply a function and store results into CSV and .npz file. As these 10 data frames are independent, I am looking to parallelize the for loop using multiprocessing but unable to get output.

```
i = 1
dfs = [df_1,df_2, df_3, df_4,df_5,df_6,df_7,df_8,df_9,df_10]

for df in dfs:        
    X = df_to_sparse(df, Q, features)
    sparse.save_npz(os.path.join(data_path, f"X-{i}"), X)
    X1 = pd.DataFrame(X.todense())
    X1.to_csv('Features_'+str(i)+'.csv', index = False)
    i = i+1
```

Comment: You need `threading` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Based on this link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143837/how-to-multi-thread-an-operation-within-a-loop-in-python>, I observed that threading doesn't help in my case.

Comment: Multiprocessing is indeed the right solution for your problem. Are you using it in Windows on Jupyter ? Because there is a known issue in that case (no output).
Multithreading is not always parrallel in Python because of the Global Interpreter Lock (aka the GIL).

Comment: @IsmaelELATIFI yes, I am on windows and running this in Jupyter notebook. I am also trying to dynamically name the csv file in multi processing.

Comment: https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac

Comment: @Sunny According to [this](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ParallelProgramming.html#Threads), most numpy operations do not hold the GIL. Since Pandas spends a lot of time inside numpy, threading is useful for some CPU-bound workloads. It depends.