# Threads Running One After One in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

**Update1:**

If I change the code inside the for loop to:

```
print('processing new page')
pool.apply_async(time.sleep, (5,))
```

I see 5 sec delay after **Every** printing, so the problem isn't related to webdriver.

**Update2:**

Thanks for @user56700 but I'm interested in knowing what did I do here and how to fix without switching from the way I'm using threads.

---

In python I have the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=Service('./chromedriver'))
for url in url:
    try:
        print('processing new page')
        result = parse_page(driver, url) # Visit url via driver, wait for it to load and parse its contents (takes 30 sec per page)
        # Change global variables
    except Exception as e:
        log_warning(str(e))
```

If I have 10 pages the above code needs 300 seconds to finish which is a lot.

I read about something called threading in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15144765/19500354 so I wanted to use it but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way.

Here's my try:

```
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
G_LOCK = threading.Lock()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=Service('./chromedriver'))
pool = Pool(10)
for url in url:
    try:
        print('processing new page')
        result = pool.apply_async(parse_page, (driver, url,)).get()
        G_LOCK.acquire()
        # Change global variables
        G_LOCK.release()
    except Exception as e:
        log_warning(str(e))

pool.close()
pool.join()

# Here I want to make sure ALL threads have finished working before running the below code
```

Why is my implementation wrong? note I'm using same driver instance

I tried to print time next to `processing new page` and I see:

```
[10:36:02] processing new page
[10:36:09] processing new page
[10:36:15] processing new page
[10:36:22] processing new page
[10:36:39] processing new page
```

Which means something is wrong as I would expect 1 sec diff nothing more. as all I'm doing is to change global variables.

Comment: Please Note that executing time before and after using threads is nearly the same. ~5 mins which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a simple example to show case how I would solve it. You need to add your own code of course.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
urls = ["https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org"]
your_data = []

def parse_page(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    data = driver.title
    return(data)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    results = {executor.submit(parse_page, driver, url) for url in urls}
    for result in as_completed(results):
        your_data.append(result.result())

driver.close()
print(your_data)
```

Result:

```
['Wikipedia', 'Wikipedia', 'Wikipedia', 'Wikipedia', 'Wikipedia']
```

If you want, you could use the webdriver as a context manager to avoid having to close it, like this:

```
with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    urls = ["https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org"]
    your_data = []

    def parse_page(driver, url):
        driver.get(url)
        data = driver.title
        return(data)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        results = {executor.submit(parse_page, driver, url) for url in urls}
        for result in as_completed(results):
            your_data.append(result.result())

print(your_data)
```

Example using the `multiprocessing.pool` library:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    urls = ["https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org", "https://www.wikipedia.org"]
    your_data = []

    def parse_page(driver, url):
        driver.get(url)
        data = driver.title
        return(data)

    pool = ThreadPool(processes=10)
    results = [pool.apply_async(parse_page, (driver, url)) for url in urls]
    for result in results:
        your_data.append(result.get())

print(your_data)
```

Result:

```
['Wikipedia', 'Wikipedia', 'Wikipedia', 'Wikipedia', 'Wikipedia']
```

Comment: Thanks, but may I know what's the problem with my specific code?

Comment: @john Well first of I would not mix different libraries, secondly you've not provided a working example to test out from. Therefore I cannot construct code that fits your exact need. I've added an example of using multiprocessing and ThreadPool in regards to my example.

Comment: Thanks last question, in: `for result in results:
        your_data.append(result.get())` part. Is it run by multiple threads (ie I need to use lock for printing inside this for loop)? or one by one?

Comment: @john `for result in results` is where you get the result of each executed thread. You can print it if you want, I just saved it to a list for simplicity sake.