# Multithread a simple for loop with independent steps

Tags: python, multithreading, performance

I have a rather complex set of fixed point equations involving integrals over the desired variables I need to solve on a grid. I can reduce the 4x4 set (4 equations and 4 variables) to 2 systems each with 2x2 dimension, where I use the solution of the first set as input for the second set. I want to solve this on a rather large grid of two input parameters with high precision as shown by the following code

```
N = 300
M = 300

A = np.linspace(-3.1,-1,N)
T = np.linspace(0.0005,.1,M)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(A, T)

v1 = 1 # Dummy variable for the code

B = np.empty(shape=(M,N))
C = np.empty(shape=(M,N))
D = np.empty(shape=(M,N))
E = np.empty(shape=(M,N))

for m in range(M):
    r = np.array([fp([a,1/T[m],v1],ini) for a in A]) # First fixed point, result [r0,r1]
    t = np.array([fP([A[a],v1,r[a,0],r[a,1]],ini2) for a in range(N)]) # second result [t0,t1]
    B[m] = r[:,0]
    C[m] = r[:,1]
    D[m] = t[:,0]
    E[m] = t[:,1]
```

where A,B,C,D in the end are NxM arrays i want to plot i a colormap. However the code is quite slow  because my functions fp and fP are complicated (i already optimized them with some help), hence i wanted to make python to usw more than one core, each processing one of the for loop steps, such that the end result of my four arrays are still ordered. However since i am not working mainly numerical (analytical physics in general) my experience with coding is limited and because of that clicking through the documentation of the multithreading package or through stackexchange did not help me in a way that I could produce a code doing this. It would be nice if somebody with a little experience could tell me how to achieve the multiprocessing on different cores of this specific problem.

Thanks in advance :)

I already vectorized all the calculations and tried to teach myself on my own how to make python use multiple cores, but without any success.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15143994/9906929) answer can help you.

Comment: Since you lack experience of coding, I will add some general advices. Relevant here as well I think. 1) write clean, understandable by others code. 2) If performance is bad, use [profiling tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script) to check where are bottlenecks.  3) If problems are computation-based, try to avoid Python loops, which are main root of slowdown. Either by vectorising your code (using `numpy`), or, if it seems hard, use `numba` package that will help you by compiling Python code and improving performance by much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15143994/9906929), so refer to it if you want more details.

Firstly turn your loop code block into a function like this (note it's passing `m` as an parameter of the function):

```py
def my_operation(m):
    r = np.array(
        [fp([a, 1 / T[m], v1], ini) for a in A]
    )  # First fixed point, result [r0,r1]
    t = np.array(
        [fP([A[a], v1, r[a, 0], r[a, 1]], ini2) for a in range(N)]
    )  # second result [t0,t1]
    B[m] = r[:, 0]
    C[m] = r[:, 1]
    D[m] = t[:, 0]
    E[m] = t[:, 1]
```

This will make it easier to parallelize things.

Now you can use [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) library to setup a thread pool to run your iterations.

```py
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
futures = [executor.submit(my_operation, m) for m in range(M)]
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Note that you can modify the number of threads by changing the parameter of `ThreadPoolExecutor()`.