# What is correct way to send mail asynchronously in python/django?

Tags: python, django

Is his the right way to do async calls to a function in python ?

**Initiator code**

```
pool = Pool(processes=4)
                pool.apply_async(send_email, ['CONFIRM', email, auth_token, password, "", first_name])
```

**Function**

```
def send_email(flag, email, auth_token='', password='', shared_by='', name=''):

    try :
            send_mail('Greetings!', 'Hi '+str(name)+'\nThank you for checking us out!'
                            'Please click on the link below to activate your subscription.\n' + confirmation_link +
              '\npassword : ' + password, 'someone@domain.com', [email],
              fail_silently=False)
    except SMTPException as e:
            print e
```

> Have I read the online documentation ?

Yes, I have but seriously  it did not help much. So I am here for assistance.

Comment: You have read the online documentation, but you didn't tell us what trouble you have with your work above.

Comment: I want to know if this is the way async needs to be done ?

Comment: Its on the top @ShangWang of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something asynchronous, integrated in Django, you need an asynchronous task queue/job. Even more if you have to send a lot of mail, it will block the Django flow.

> Task queues manage background work that must be executed outside the 
>   usual HTTP request-response cycle.
>
> Tasks are handled asynchronously either because they are not initiated
>   by an HTTP request or because they are long-running jobs that would
>   dramatically reduce the performance of an HTTP response.

There are several task queue system that integrate well with Django like **Celery** ([docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)). I recommend you to read this to understand and choose the right solution : [Full Stack Python - Task queues](http://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html)

Comment: Yes i read about celery and what you said about overloading my django is also undeniable. I would additionally want to know if the above code will work asynchronously or not ? Because i think its still blocking my response from reaching the browser , but when i kill the process in which its running then i get response in the browser. So i think there is something wrong in the above code. Can you help ?

Comment: I can't help you in that way, I written some server in python and to handle task asynchronously, I used Thread. Concerning your code, I can't help you to resolve this code. I think that Pool object are not easy to integrated in module since Django is a Framework and it fix some rules : [check that maybe it can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947876/using-python-multiprocessing-pool-in-the-terminal-and-in-code-modules-for-django). But I can tell you that It's not the correct way to do what you want. You have to use task queue/job.

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro thanks for the response, but why can't I make a simple asynchronous request using package `aiohttp` in python. It just requests mail api asynchronously right ?

Comment: I don't know how I missed accepting this answer. So sorry @LouisBarranqueiro