# Python multiprocessing Pool Interaction With Namespace At Creation

Tags: python, multiprocessing

We know that `multiprocessing.Pool` must be initialized after the definitions of functions to run on them. However I found the code below is inscrutable for me

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(i): print('first')

pool1 = Pool(2)
pool1.map(func, range(2))         #map-1

def func(i): print('second')
func2 = func

print('------')
pool1.map(func,  range(2))        #map-2
pool1.map(func2,  range(2))       #map-3

pool2 = Pool(2)
print('------')
pool2.map(func,   range(2))       #map-4
pool2.map(func2,  range(2))       #map-5
```

The output (python2.7 and python3.4 on linux) is

```
first         #map-1
first
------
first         #map-2
first
first         #map-3
first
------
second        #map-4
second
second        #map-5
second
```

`map-2` print `'first'` just as we expected. 
But how does `map-3` find the name `func2`? I mean `pool1` is initialized before the `func2` 's first occurrence. So `func2 = func` is indeed executed, while `def func(i): print('second')` is not. Why?

And if I define func2 directly by

```
def func2(i): print('second')
```

Then `map-3` won't find name `func2` as mentioned by many posts, eg. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947876/using-python-multiprocessing-pool-in-the-terminal-and-in-code-modules-for-django). What's the difference between two cases?

As I understand the arguments are passed to the slave processes by pickling, but
how does `pool` pass the called function to other processes? Or how do sub-processes find the called function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: the issue at `map-3` where the first `func` is being called, when one would expect the second `func` to be is due to the fact that `Pool.map()` serializes `func.__name__` with pickle which resolves to `func` even though it's being assigned to the `func2` reference, and is sent to the child process, which looks up the `func` locally to the child process.

---

---

ok so I can count four different questions, listed below, and I consider you're already lectured about namespaces and forking processes, to get straight into the fun of your question ☺

> ① But how does map-3 find the name func2?
>
> ② So func2 = func is indeed executed, while def func(i): print('second') is not. Why?
>
> ③ Then map-3 won't find name func2 as mentioned by many posts, eg. this one. What's the difference between two cases?
>
> ④ As I understand the arguments are passed to the slave processes by pickling, but how does pool pass the called function to other processes? Or how do sub-processes find the called function?

So I've added a bit more code, to show off more of the internals:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

print(os.getpid(), 'parent')

def func(i):
    print(os.getpid(), 'first', end=" | ")
    if 'func' in globals():
        print(globals()['func'], end=" | ")
    else:
        print("no func in globals", end=" | ")
    if 'func2' in globals():
        print(globals()['func2'])
    else:
        print("no func2 in globals")

print('------ map-1')
pool1 = Pool(2)
pool1.map(func, range(2))         #map-1

def func(i):
    print(os.getpid(), 'second', end=" | ")
    if 'func' in globals():
        print(globals()['func'], end=" | ")
    else:
        print("no func in globals", end=" | ")
    if 'func2' in globals():
        print(globals()['func2'])
    else:
        print("no func2 in globals")
func2 = func

print('------ map-2')
pool1.map(func,  range(2))        #map-2
print('------ map-3')
pool1.map(func2,  range(2))       #map-3

pool2 = Pool(2)
print('------ map-4')
pool2.map(func,   range(2))       #map-4
print('------ map-5')
pool2.map(func2,  range(2))       #map-5
```

which outputs on my system:

```
21512 parent
------ map-1
21513 first | <function func at 0x7f62d67f7cf8> | no func2 in globals
21514 first | <function func at 0x7f62d67f7cf8> | no func2 in globals
------ map-2
21513 first | <function func at 0x7f62d67f7cf8> | no func2 in globals
21514 first | <function func at 0x7f62d67f7cf8> | no func2 in globals
------ map-3
21513 first | <function func at 0x7f62d67f7cf8> | no func2 in globals
21514 first | <function func at 0x7f62d67f7cf8> | no func2 in globals
------ map-4
21518 second | <function func at 0x7f62d531bed8> | <function func at 0x7f62d531bed8>
21519 second | <function func at 0x7f62d531bed8> | <function func at 0x7f62d531bed8>
------ map-5
21518 second | <function func at 0x7f62d531bed8> | <function func at 0x7f62d531bed8>
21519 second | <function func at 0x7f62d531bed8> | <function func at 0x7f62d531bed8>
```

so, we can see that for `pool1` there never is a `func2` being added to the namespace. So there is definitely something fishy going on there, and it's being too late for me to look thoroughly at the source of `multiprocessing` and at the debugger to understand what's going on.

So if I had to guess an answer to ①, the `pickle` module is finding out somehow that `func2` resolves to `0x7f62d531bed8`, which already exists with the tag `func`, thus it pickles the already known "label" `func` on the children side, resolving there to `0x7f62d67f7cf8`. i.e.:

```
func2 → 0x7f62d531bed8 → func → [PICKLE] → globals()['func'] → 0x7f62d67f7cf8
```

To test my theory, I changed your code a bit, by renaming the second `func()` into `func2()` and here is what I got:

```
------ map-3
Process PoolWorker-1:
Process PoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func2'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func2'
```

and then changing as well `func = func2` into `func2 = func`

```
------ map-2
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Process PoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func2'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func2'
```

So I believe I'm starting to make a point. And also, it shows where to read the code to understand what's going on, on the children processes side.

So that more clues to answer ② and ③!

To get further, I added a print statement within `pool.py` line 114:

```
    job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    print("XXX", os.getpid(), job, i, func, args, kwds)
```

to show what's going on. And we can see that `func` is resolved to `0x7f2d0238fcf8`, which is the same address as within the parent function:

```
23432 parent
------ map-1
('XXX', 23433, 0, 0, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8>, (0,)),), {})
23433 first | <function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8> | no func2 in globals
('XXX', 23434, 0, 1, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8>, (1,)),), {})
23434 first | <function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8> | no func2 in globals
------ map-2
('XXX', 23433, 1, 0, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8>, (0,)),), {})
23433 first | <function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8> | no func2 in globals
('XXX', 23434, 1, 1, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8>, (1,)),), {})
23434 first | <function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8> | no func2 in globals
------ map-3
('XXX', 23433, 2, 0, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8>, (0,)),), {})
23433 first | <function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8> | no func2 in globals
('XXX', 23434, 2, 1, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8>, (1,)),), {})
23434 first | <function func at 0x7f2d0238fcf8> | no func2 in globals
------ map-4
('XXX', 23438, 3, 0, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x1092e60>, (0,)),), {})
23438 second | <function func at 0x1092e60> | <function func at 0x1092e60>
('XXX', 23439, 3, 1, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x1092e60>, (1,)),), {})
23439 second | <function func at 0x1092e60> | <function func at 0x1092e60>
------ map-5
('XXX', 23438, 4, 0, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x1092e60>, (0,)),), {})
('XXX', 23439, 4, 1, <function mapstar at 0x7f2d02363230>, ((<function func at 0x1092e60>, (1,)),), {})
23438 second | <function func at 0x1092e60> | <function func at 0x1092e60>
23439 second | <function func at 0x1092e60> | <function func at 0x1092e60>
```

So to answer ④, we'd need to dig further in the multiprocessing sources, and even maybe within the pickle sources.

But I guess my feeling about the resolution is likely to be right…
And then the only remaining question is *why* does it resolves labels to addresses and back to labels again, before pushing that to children processes!

---

edit: I think I know why! As I was going to bed, the reason popped in my head, so I just went back to my keyboard:

When pickling the function, pickles takes the argument containing the function, and gets its name from the function's object itself:

so even though if you do create a new function object, for which you do get a different address in memory:

```
>>> print(func)
<function func at 0x7fc6174e3ed8>
```

pickles doesn't care, because if the function is not already accessible by the child, it will never be made accessible. So pickle only resolves `func.__name__`:

```
>>> print("func.__name__:", func.__name__)
func.__name__: func
>>> print("func2.__name__:", func2.__name__)
func2.__name__: func
```

and then, even though you changed the function's body on the parent thread, and you made a new reference to that function, what really gets pickled is the internal name of the function, which is given when the lambda gets assigned or the function is defined.

This explains why you get the old `func` function when you give `func2` to the `pool1` at the `map-3` stage.

So as a conclusion, for ① `map-3` does not find the name `func2`, it find the name `func` within the function referred by `func2`. So, that also answers ② & ③, as because the `func` being found is executing the original `func` function. And the mechanism, is the fact that `func.__name__` is being used to pickle and resolve the function name between the two processes, answering ④.

---

Last update, from you:

In `pickle._Pickler.save_global`, it gets the name using

```
if name is None: name = getattr(obj, '__qualname__', None)
```

then again

```
if name is None: name = obj.__name__.
```

So if the obj has no `__qualname__` then `__name__` will be used.

> *However it will check if the object passed is same with the one in subprocess:*

```
if obj2 is not obj: raise PicklingError(...)
```

where `obj2, parent = _getattribute(module, name)`.

yup, but remember that the object passed is just the (internal) name of the function, not the function itself. The child process has **no** way of finding out whether his `func()` is the same as the parent's `func()` in memory.

---

Edit from @SyrtisMajor:

OK, let's change the first code above:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

print(os.getpid(), 'parent')

def func(i):
    print(os.getpid(), 'first', end=" | ")
    if 'func' in globals():
        print(globals()['func'], end=" | ")
    else:
        print("no func in globals", end=" | ")
    if 'func2' in globals():
        print(globals()['func2'])
    else:
        print("no func2 in globals")

print('------ map-1')
pool1 = Pool(2)
pool1.map(func, range(2))         #map-1

def func2(i):
    print(os.getpid(), 'second', end=" | ")
    if 'func' in globals():
        print(globals()['func'], end=" | ")
    else:
        print("no func in globals", end=" | ")
    if 'func2' in globals():
        print(globals()['func2'])
    else:
        print("no func2 in globals")

func2.__qualname__ = func.__qualname__   

func = func2

print('------ map-2')
pool1.map(func,  range(2))        #map-2
print('------ map-3')
pool1.map(func2,  range(2))       #map-3

pool2 = Pool(2)
print('------ map-4')
pool2.map(func,   range(2))       #map-4
print('------ map-5')
pool2.map(func2,  range(2))       #map-5
```

The outputs is as follow:

```
38130 parent
------ map-1
38131 first | <function func at 0x101856f28> | no func2 in globals
38132 first | <function func at 0x101856f28> | no func2 in globals
------ map-2
38131 first | <function func at 0x101856f28> | no func2 in globals
38132 first | <function func at 0x101856f28> | no func2 in globals
------ map-3
38131 first | <function func at 0x101856f28> | no func2 in globals
38132 first | <function func at 0x101856f28> | no func2 in globals
------ map-4
38133 second | <function func at 0x10339b510> | <function func at 0x10339b510>
38134 second | <function func at 0x10339b510> | <function func at 0x10339b510>
------ map-5
38133 second | <function func at 0x10339b510> | <function func at 0x10339b510>
38134 second | <function func at 0x10339b510> | <function func at 0x10339b510>
```

It's exactly the same as our first output. And note that `func = func2` after the definition of `func2` is key as pickle will check if the `func2` (with name `func`) is same as `__main__.func`. If no, then pickling will fail.

Comment: N.B.: it's almost 5am here, and I'm now too tired to keep on digging this very interesting issue!

Comment: Great job! It does make sense and explain all my questions. Thank you, I have learned a lot from it. I'll (try to) check the code of multiprocessing later.

Comment: Aha, it is interesting. It seems it's `__qualname__` . I defined a new `func2` and assign `func.__qualname__` to it. Then the traceback says `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function func at 0x1234abcde>: it's not the same object as __main__.func`.  There is no space for pasting the full traceback, anyway according to traceback we may take a look at `multiprocessing/reduction.py, line 50, in dumps: cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)`.

Comment: In `pickle._Pickler.save_global`, it gets the name by `if name is None: name = getattr(obj, '__qualname__', None)` then again `if name is None: name = obj.__name__`. So if the obj has no `__qualname__` then `__name__` will be used. However it will check if the object passed is same with the one in subprocess: `if obj2 is not obj: raise PicklingError(...)` where `obj2, parent = _getattribute(module, name)`.

Comment: ok, now I think I'm done with that issue ☺ cheers, syrtis! 

Comment: Cheers! Feel free to reject or modify my edits :)  Ah, there is another question actually.  I'm not sure the passed-in function is check with the one in subprocess or main process. It seems like to be main process as it shows in the last example. Anyway the one in subprocess is the one executes without doubts.

Comment: It seems to be mainly a problem of `pickle` instead of `multiprocessing`.  The [doc of pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) says, `Note that functions ...  are pickled by “fully qualified” name reference, not by value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled.` and so do the classes. Yeah, that's exactly what we've found here. I've just missed this when reading the doc of pickle :-P