# Unexpected behavior using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have a dictionary with significant amount of key value pairs.

and I have function to iterate the dictionary and perform some operations.

I have done something like this.

```
poolExecutor = Pool()
for k, v in id_values_dict.items():
    poolExecutor.apply_async(build_payload, (k, v, results, id, get_uuid))
poolExecutor.close()
poolExecutor.join()

def build_payload(k, v, results, id, get_uuid):
   <operations to be performed>
```

The function never returns throwing exceptions like following,

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from '__main__' (unknown location)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\nm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "c:\users\nm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "c:\users\nm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "c:\users\nm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "c:\users\nm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

You can see there is an import error there `ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from '__main__' (unknown location)`
but I don't get this error if i am not using multiprocessing.

Can you explain what is going wrong here.

Comment: Try putting the first part of your snippet that used `Pool` in side a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard (but not the function definition which should come before that).

Comment: @martineau, you are right.  But the issue is my project is fairly big and cannot put ```pool``` inside ```__main__```.  Have a look at this answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18947948/13511372)

Comment: You must prevent the guraded code from executing every time the script for the main process is imported, which happens multiple times on Windows. Seems like you could put the `Pool` stuff inside a function that's only called from the main processes when its `__name__ == '__main__':` (or at the top level of a module that's only import when it is). If that measn you have to restructure you project, regardless of its size, then so be it.