# Multiprocessing over grid points of a 2D function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a two dimensional function and I want to compute the elements of the function on the grid points but the two loops over rows and columns are very slow and I want to use `multiprocessing` to increase the speed of the code. I have written the following code to do two loops:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

#Grid points
ra = np.linspace(25.1446, 25.7329, 1000)
dec = np.linspace(-10.477, -9.889, 1000)
#The 2D function
def like2d(x,y): 
    stuff=[RaDec, beta, rho_c_over_sigma_c, zhalo, rho_crit]
    m=3e14
    c=7.455
    param=[x, y, m, c]
    return reduced_shear( param, stuff, observed_g, g_err)

pool = Pool(processes=12)

def data_stream(a, b):
    for i, av in enumerate(a):
        for j, bv in enumerate(b):
            yield (i, j), (av, bv)

def myfunc(args):
    return args[0], like2d(*args[1])

counter,likelihood = pool.map(myfunc, data_stream(ra, dec))
```

But I got the following error message:

Process PoolWorker-1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myfunc'
Process PoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myfunc'
Process PoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myfunc'
Process PoolWorker-4:
```

Everything is defined and I do not understand why this error message raised!! Can anybody point out what might be wrong?

Another approach to do loops with `multiprocessing` and save the results in a 2d array:

```
#Grid points
ra = np.linspace(25.1446, 25.7329, 1000)
dec = np.linspace(-10.477, -9.889, 1000)

#The 2D function
def like2d(x,y):
    stuff=[RaDec, beta, rho_c_over_sigma_c, zhalo, rho_crit]
    m=3e14
    c=7.455
    param=[x, y, m, c]
    return reduced_shear( param, stuff, observed_g, g_err)


shared_array_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, ra.shape[0]*dec.shape[0])
shared_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base.get_obj())
shared_array = shared_array.reshape( ra.shape[0],dec.shape[0])

# Parallel processing
def my_func(i, def_param=shared_array):
    shared_array[i,:] = np.array([float(like2d(ra[j],dec[i])) for j in range(ra.shape[0])])

print "processing to estimate likelihood in 2D grids......!!!"
start = time.time()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12)
pool.map(my_func, range(dec.shape[0]))
print shared_array
end = time.time()
print end - start
```

Comment: As an aside, if you have less than 12 CPU cores on your machine, you're probably only going to hurt performance by creating 12 processes to do CPU-bound work. Your CPUs can only actually have `num_cpus` processes at once, so the rest are just wasting memory and causing the OS to have to context switch excessively. If you *do* have 12 or more cores, lucky you!

Comment: @dano I have access to a cluster and I can fork even more!

Comment: possible duplicate of [yet another confusion with multiprocessing error, 'module' object has no attribute 'f'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782961/yet-another-confusion-with-multiprocessing-error-module-object-has-no-attribu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create the `Pool` after the worker function (`myfunc`) definition. Creating the `Pool` causes Python to fork your worker processes right at that point, and the only things that will be defined in the children are the functions defined above the `Pool` definition. Also, `map` will return a list of tuples (one for each object `yield`ed by `data_stream`), not a single tuple. So you need this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

#Grid points
ra = np.linspace(25.1446, 25.7329, 1000)
dec = np.linspace(-10.477, -9.889, 1000)
#The 2D function
def like2d(x,y): 
    stuff=[RaDec, beta, rho_c_over_sigma_c, zhalo, rho_crit]
    m=3e14
    c=7.455
    param=[x, y, m, c]
    return reduced_shear( param, stuff, observed_g, g_err)


def data_stream(a, b):
    for i, av in enumerate(a):
        for j, bv in enumerate(b):
            yield (i, j), (av, bv)

def myfunc(args):
    return args[0], like2d(*args[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    results = pool.map(myfunc, data_stream(ra, dec))  # results is a list of tuples.
    for counter,likelihood in results:
        print("counter: {}, likelihood: {}".format(counter, likelihood))
```

I added the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard, which isn't necessary on POSIX platforms, but would be necessary on Windows (which doesn't support `os.fork()`).

Comment: If my operation system is `linux` I don't need `if __name__ == "__main__":`, right? What does it do?

Comment: @Dalek If you're only worried about Linux you can leave it out. It protects the entry point of your script - anything inside that statement won't be executed when your module is `import`ed. It will only run if someone actually calls your script directly (e.g. using `python yourscript.py`). This is necessary on Windows because it can't use `os.fork`, so it has to re-import your module to spawn the worker processes. If you don't use `if __name__ == "__main__":` to protect the spot you actually create the `Process`, it'll end up trying to repreatedly creat the `Process` object in the children.

Comment: @Dalek See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) for more info on that.

Comment: the problem with your answer is at the end the out put 'results' is a list with mixed up rows and columns, while I want that the output would be a 2D array.

Comment: @Dalek I'm just using the code you provided. You're calling `myfunc` with `pool.map`. `myfunc` returns a tuple, where the first arg is the `(i,j)` returned by `data_stream`, and the second arg is the return value of `like2d(av, bv)`. The return value of `like2d(av, bv)` is whatever `reduced_shear` returns (I have no idea what that returns). The `map` function will always return a list of the return value of every call to `myfunc`, which means it's going to return a list of tuples. If you want to turn that list of tuples into a 2D-array, you have to do that afterwards.

Comment: I tried to see whether there are returned by the order of the columns of each row but when I plot it the indices are mixed up. Is there anyway to return the output into an array in first place?

Comment: @Dalek Can you edit your question to show how you would do this without concurrency? I'm really have no idea what you're actually trying to do on the `numpy` side of the world. I might be able to tell you how to use `multiprocessing` here properly if I know more about your actual goal.

Comment: I will figure it out! It is too late and I just was lazy! Thanks!