# python pool doesn't work

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to use multithreading and in order to keep it simple at first, i'm running the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(4)

def square(x):

    return x**2

results=pool.map(square,range(1,20))
```

As i understand, results should be a list containig the squares from 1 to 20.
However, the code does not seem to terminate.(doing the same  without pool finishes in a blink, this ran for several minutes, before i stopped it manually).

Additional information: task manager tells me, that the additional python processes have been launched and are running, but are using zero % of my cpu; still other unrelated processes like firefox skyrocket in their cpu usage, while the programm is running. 
I'm using windows 8 and a i5-4300U cpu (pooling to 2 instead of 4 doesn't help either)

What am i doing wrong?
Are there any good ressources on the Pool class, which could help me understand what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try reversing order in which you instantiate pool and define square

Comment: On Python 3.4 / Linux I'm getting AttributeErrors thrown by the pool processes

Comment: Read the Windows-specific tips in the multiprocessing documentation, paying particular attention to the need for `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Answer (score 7):

Code with pool initialization should be inside `__name__ == "__main__"` as `multiprocessing` imports the module each time to spawn a new process.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def square(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    results=pool.map(square,range(1,20))
```

Comment: Why is this not in the documentation?

Comment: @Alper it is in the docs, check "Safe importing of main module" under https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

Comment: OK. But this is a case where I am amazed by how bad the Python documentation is (and I'm not exactly new to Python).

Answer (score 0):

Your code causes each process to hit an attribute error because it can't find the `square` attribute because it wasn't defined when you instantiated the pool. The processes therefore hang thereafter. Defining square before pool would fix the problem.

See also:

[yet another confusion with multiprocessing error, 'module' object has no attribute 'f'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782961/yet-another-confusion-with-multiprocessing-error-module-object-has-no-attribu)

Comment: this did not work on its own, however a comment in the link you provided made me use import multiprocessing as mp
def square(x):
 return x**2
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    results=pool.map(square,range(1,20))            i'm unsure how to format this, so there are two follow up questions: how to format comments in here( enter makes me submit) and how is this ominous if statement making the code work?