# Shared pool map between processes with object-oriented python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

(**python2.7**)

I'm trying to do a kind of scanner, that has to walk through CFG nodes, and split in different processes on branching for parallelism purpose.

The scanner is represented by an object of class Scanner. This class has one method **traverse** that walks through the said graph and splits if necessary.

Here how it looks:

```
class Scanner(object):
    def __init__(self, atrb1, ...):
       self.attribute1 = atrb1
       self.process_pool = Pool(processes=4)
    def traverse(self, ...):
        [...]
        if branch:
           self.process_pool.map(my_func, todo_list).
```

My problem is the following:
How do I create a instance of multiprocessing.Pool, that is shared between all of my processes ? I want it to be shared, because since a path can be splitted again, I do not want to end with a kind of fork bomb, and having the same Pool will help me to limit the number of processes running at the same time.

The above code does not work, since Pool can not be pickled. In consequence, I have tried that:

```
class Scanner(object):
   def __getstate__(self):
      self_dict  = self.__dict__.copy()
      def self_dict['process_pool']
      return self_dict
    [...]
```

But obviously, it results in having **self.process_pool** not defined in the created processes.

Then, I tried to create a Pool as a module attribute:

```
process_pool = Pool(processes=4)

def my_func(x):
    [...]

class Scanner(object):
    def __init__(self, atrb1, ...):
       self.attribute1 = atrb1
    def traverse(self, ...):
        [...]
        if branch:
           process_pool.map(my_func, todo_list)
```

It does not work, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782961/yet-another-confusion-with-multiprocessing-error-module-object-has-no-attribu) explains why.
But here comes the thing, wherever I create my Pool, something is missing. If I create this Pool at the end of my file, it does not see self.attribute1, the same way it did not see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782961/yet-another-confusion-with-multiprocessing-error-module-object-has-no-attribu) and fails with an AttributeError.

I'm not even trying to share it yet, and I'm already stuck with Multiprocessing way of doing thing.

I don't know if I have not been thinking correctly the whole thing, but I can not believe it's so complicated to handle something as simple as "having a worker pool and giving them tasks".

Thank you,

**EDIT**:
I resolved my first problem (AttributeError), my class had a callback as its attribute, and this callback was defined in the main script file, after the import of the scanner module... But the concurrency and "do not fork bomb" thing is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can't be done safely. Think about if you somehow had a single shared `Pool` shared across parent and worker processes, with, say, two worker processes. The parent runs a `map` that tries to perform two tasks, and each task needs to `map` two more tasks. The two parent dispatched tasks go to each worker, and the parent blocks. Each worker sends two more tasks to the shared pool and blocks for them to complete. But now all workers are now occupied, waiting for a worker to become free; you've deadlocked.

A safer approach would be to have the workers return enough information to dispatch additional tasks in the parent. Then you could do something like:

```
class MoreWork(object):
    def __init__(self, func, *args):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
try:
    base_task = somefunc, someargs
    outstanding = collections.deque([pool.apply_async(*base_task)])
    while outstanding:
        result = outstanding.popleft().get()
        if isinstance(result, MoreWork):
            outstanding.append(pool.apply_async(result.func, result.args))
        else:
            ... do something with a "final" result, maybe breaking the loop ...
finally:
     pool.terminate()
```

What the functions are is up to you, they'd just return information in a `MoreWork` when there was more to do, not launch a task directly. The point is to ensure that by having the parent be solely responsible for task dispatch, and the workers solely responsible for task completion, you can't deadlock due to all workers being blocked waiting for tasks that are in the queue, but not being processed.

This is also not at all optimized; ideally, you wouldn't block waiting on the first item in the queue if other items in the queue were complete; it's a lot easier to do this with the `concurrent.futures` module, specifically with [`concurrent.futures.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) to wait on the first available result from an arbitrary number of outstanding tasks, but you'd need a third party PyPI package to get `concurrent.futures` on Python 2.7.