# Solution to multiprocessing error in Ipython Notebook?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipython

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing module in Ipython Notebook, however when I execute my code, it crashes the Kernel:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

p = Pool(8)
p.map(f, [1, 2, 3])
```

The docs provide this bit of information:

> Functionality within this package requires that the **main** module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter

However, the module seems to work for some, such as in [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ResearchComputing/Python-HPC-Spring-2013/blob/master/08_parallel/multiprocessing.ipynb).
Other stackoverflow threads indicate that you should rearrange your code like so:

[yet another confusion with multiprocessing error, 'module' object has no attribute 'f'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782961/yet-another-confusion-with-multiprocessing-error-module-object-has-no-attribu)

But I'm still getting the same error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

I'm using Windows 8, Python 2.7.12, and the latest versions of IPython Notebook/Anaconda distribution.

Is there a definitive solution for this bug?

Is the source of the error really the lack of `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement?

Is this a Windows specific issue, or does it apply to Unix as well?