# Multiprocessing error when running simple examples

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, attributeerror

I have been trying to optimize some functions by running some parallel code using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) lib
but for some reason it isn't working (in the cmd, spyder and jupyter).

Actually im getting an endless loop process and an AttributteError

I tested some simple functions to try to understand what i was doing wrong, but i think it is not a code problem and i cant figure out whats the problem.

thanks!

[image: answer to duplicate]
[image: answer to duplicate2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yet another confusion with multiprocessing error, 'module' object has no attribute 'f'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782961/yet-another-confusion-with-multiprocessing-error-module-object-has-no-attribu)

Comment: No, i've got the same error while passing the function before creating the pool

Comment: It's working for me when I use the solution described there

Comment: Irrelevant but just to let you know, this killed my kernel in jupyter. I couldn't even restart it. I closed jupyter completely and still could not restart it as I was getting `AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'`. I found that this is related to the version of tornado>=5.0. More info [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8374). I fixed this by uninstalling tornado5.0 and installing tornado4.5.3.

Comment: @user8212173 It killed mine too. I had to `CTRL + Z` to stop the entire process then manually kill each child process and finally the repl

Comment: i will try to reinstall anaconda

Comment: @smac89, mine didn't even work after killing child processes, it was stuck in an endless loop of `AttributeError`s. This seems to be specific to Windows only as pointed out [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10894)

Comment: @PatrickNasser, not sure if this will help as its a Windows specific issue. But do let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the square method before the Pool. Full example:

```
➜ python3      
Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar 13 2018, 09:50:23) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170519] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> 
>>> def sq(x):
...     return x * x
... 
>>> with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
...     results = pool.map(sq, [1,2,3,4,5])
... 
>>> print (results)
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>>
```

Comment: didin't worked :/ i added the two last images in the original post to show it...  in my original code the functions was also defined before,.. i ll remove the wrong example that i tested  in edit

Comment: This is probably a windows issue. Can you try explicitly passing the number of processes to the `Pool`. So like `Pool(2)`

Comment: im using anaconda, through jupyterlab, spyder and the command prompt, neither of them worked

Comment: @PatrickNasser, take the code you have now and put it in a file like `example.py`, then do the pool stuff within an if statement that reads `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Run the script with your python and see if that works

Comment: I just saw now @user8212173 previous comment in the original question! Now i got it, thanks! (im pissed of with my pc right now haha)